# Can we rename [dnd-next] to [dnd-next-playtest] before it's released?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, dnd-5e

The 5th release of D&D is due for release in ["Summer 2014"](http://company.wizards.com/content/wizards-coast-announces-thrilling-dungeons-dragons-launch-summer-2014), which means sometime soon. As far as I'm aware, it does not have a definite name yet: it might be D&D 5th Edition, or retain its name of D&D Next.

Currently we have the [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) tag, which has the synonyms [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) and [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e). It would be very messy if questions about the playtest & the release get mixed up in one tag. So, let's not leave that too late - it would be inconvenient if we had a flood of 5e questions on the first release days before anyone remembers to change over the tags.

Could we action [this suggestion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3520/1204) and rename the [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) tag to [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest), and decouple it from its synonyms, leaving [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) and [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) ready to use (and create anew) when the game's released?

Comment: I just realised that SSD's suggestion only came along a day before I asked this - I must've missed the timestamps somehow; I thought it was much older, like everything else in that question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After three more years (!) and considerably more questions, it became clear that a division developed between old playtest questions and questions that are or can be made into questions about the current published D&D 5e rules. This lead to some old questions (tagged [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)) that were only meaningful in the context of the original playtest documents attracting new answers citing the published hardcover books, as seen in these examples:

- [Meta] [Revisiting whether D&D Next needs its own separate tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/revisiting-whether-dd-next-needs-its-own-separate-tag) (mainsite questions mentioned in answers)
- [Spell DC Saving Throws](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35692/spell-dc-saving-throws) (deleted answers, 10k+ only)
- [Ack! Where do I find the spell descriptions for casters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/ack-where-do-i-find-the-spell-descriptions-for-casters) (deleted answers, 10k+ only)

To that end, the need to section off questions that could only be about the playtest materials became clear. That's now been done, and they live under the [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) tag.

Comment: Bravo.  Glad to see this step taken, I wonder if I am one of the offenders in this matter.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Not that I recall! Mostly new users innocently arriving via a “D&D 5e” search and landing on a question they could answer, unaware (typically blamelessly) that the question labelled “dnd-5e” wasn't actually about the released D&D 5e rules.

Comment: [status-better-late-than-never] I'm happy to see us do this too. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd really rather not, I don't understand the value in doing so. That seems way to deep down into the sub-sub-versions.  We don't have a pathfinder-beta tag, or a dnd-4e-essentials tag. I think their date and content makes it clear it's about the playtest.

Comment: Was this site around when the Pathfinder beta was happening? A 4e Essentials/non-Essentials split is _not_ analogous to a beta split, so I prefer we not get into that: betas are agreeably distinct from and superseded by their final release, especially in this case where there's a lot of clean-up work to do. The D&D 4e essentials/non-essentials thing just describes two sides of the same product, which were never made distinct, and the community has varying opinions on how distinct they are.

Comment: If we take a convention of not splitting beta versions off from the original product, I'll accept that if it works out well. (Just: that's a different matter to the Essentials issue.)

Comment: Brian suggested we make sure the old Next Q&As are updated to reflect the new rules once they're out. Whether that should be done aside, *if* it's done then it might be easier to segregate them by tag beforehand. Then again, while writing this I recalled that we can add `is:question created:2014-08..2010-01` to search terms just to find the pre-release Qs, so perhaps it's not necessary even then. Anyway.

Comment: Yeah, we've never distingushed alphas, betas, play tests, reprints, etc and I think just saying "play test" in the Q is enough, no need to go back and rework them (likely won't make sense /little value)

Answer (score 3):

I've written a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/186581/dd-next-playtest-queries) to show all [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) activity with a last activity before July 31st.

This way, we'll have a simple list of next questions that haven't been touched.

We should differentiate questions that are about a specific playtest packet (and either discuss features that have slipped out, or other nonsense) and make it clear in the question which specific playtest it's about.

For other questions, we'll just need to answer all of them with the latest details or ask the answerers to clean up their questions.

Answer (score 0):

If a Dnd-Next-Playtest tag is created, it should NOT replace the Dnd-Next tag, and it's even possible that it should be kept seperate from the DnD5e tag.

My reasoning is as follows. The Playtest is now over. One is not able to gain access to the latest playtest rules (they go up to level 20) legally.

However, if you purchase one of the encounters modules, such as Dead in Thay or Vault of the Dracolitch or Ghosts Of Dragonspear Castle, you do get a version of the rules.  those rules only go up to level 10, and are missing some other content, like Warforged race.

That is, you can currently purchase the Dnd-Next rules, but you can not purchase the playtest rules, and you can not purchase the 5e rules.

Also, I'll try to go through all the questions and amswer with the latest dnd next rules

Comment: The idea isn't for the D&D Next tag to go away and be replaced by it completely - just that every question _currently_ with the D&D Next tag gets it turned into a D&D Next Playtest tag, and new questions based on regular material can use the D&D Next tag anew.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that some of the current questions are for D&D next , and not the playtest. Any question after November 2013 would be Next and not Playtest.

Comment: There are questions after November 2013, [like this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923/1204), which are still about the playtest rules packet though.

Comment: @doppelgreener Why do you think it's about the playtest rules packet and not the Ghost of Dragonspear castle packet?

Comment: Ah, the accepted answer. But Chase's second answer makes me think otherwise.