# Can we make dnd-5e the default and dnd-next the synonym?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

With D&D 5e's Basic Rules released today I think that we should make 5e the default tag that shows up and make dnd-next the synonym (its the other way around currently).

Answer (score 7):

I concur. We should have [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) as the "real" tag, because "Dungeons & Dragons" is what it's being called, and it's the 5th in this particular edition-numbering series.

Then [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) should be a synonym of [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), since [consensus seems to be to not have a separate tag for the playtest period rules](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/can-we-rename-dnd-next-to-dnd-next-playtest-before-its-released).

Comment: How is the internet in general referring to it?

Comment: Internet seems to be referring to it as the 5th edition, and D&D next for obvious historical reasons.

Comment: For future readers: per the linked meta, [dnd-next-playtest] did eventually end up getting made as a separate tag from [dnd-5e].

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some value at this point in separating them. The DnD Next questions deal with playtest-specific issues in some cases, so I would be more inclined to have [dnd-5e] and [dnd-5e-playtest] with [dnd-next] linked to the latter. Probably we should also go and look at which questions are still relevant to 5e (based on the Basic Rules) and tag them as both.

Comment: See this answer, The mods and the community seem to think that ultimately its better to have 1 tag per edition

Comment: [Can we rename \[dnd-next\] to \[dnd-next-playtest\] before it's released?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/can-we-rename-dnd-next-to-dnd-next-playtest-before-its-released)