# How can we go about getting advanced copies of D&D Next's releases?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In, [How can we make D&D Next a home run for RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/how-can-we-make-dd-next-a-home-run-for-rpg-se) it was suggested (and I agree) that one of the best ways we could go about generating site traffic, increasing the user base, and solidifying our community as the go-to place for Expert Answers was to secure copies of D&D Next so we would be able to provide launch day answers. How would we as a community go about reaching out to WOTC to try to get some copies? Should we try to get both the Starter Set (released in July) and the PHB (released in august)?

Comment: On Arqade this is done through the network staff (the community team, I believe), rather than having the individual SE members try to contact a publisher directly.

Comment: I figured it was done through some kind of hierarchy if we were going to do it officially, was posting this so the Diamond Mods could go about contacting the appropriate people, try to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Is the last playtest version not good enough to be prepared? (I admit I've lost track of the exact status, so it's entirely possible that their changes are too dramatic for the playtest version to have any relevance.)

Comment: @mcv It's not, each playtest version was like an experiment with various rules and approaches rather than an iterative change to a finished product. The final version to be published is supposed to have modular rules so that it can be molded to fit your group's preferred playstyle. Even if this were not true and it the final playtest was very similar/almost complete version of what will be published we still wouldn't be able to cite it because of publishing differences.

Comment: We've contacted community.

Answer (score 6):

I'm Grace Note, a Stack Exchange Community Manager.

There's still some active discussion going on internally about specifics. Getting some advance copies would probably be handy but we'd need some kind of way to determine how to distribute them, and then when launch hits it would be handy to have some kind of [promotional call for questions](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-can-i-help-promote-sports-se-as-a-destination-for-olympics-questions) so that the folks who can now answer, actually have stuff to answer. We'll be happy to match efforts in formulating ideas on how to set it all up.

In regards to what we can offer, what we'd like most is to see how much we can get done with less developer/designer effort. The goal should be primarily focused on content generation - the creation of an awesome canon here is far more important than drawing reader traffic alone. Now, with advance copies to help setup that kind of a canon, that's looking in the right direction. When we've worked together betwixt us to work out some ideas on how to actually manage all this, we can handle the work regarding getting the actual copies and such.

Comment: I've seen a couple of promos at Arqade so I know what the end result looks like, but how do we go about designing one? We're creative people, but marketing isn't our domain of expertise; some best practices, or a framework, or something like that would be useful to build off of.